# Prove that if J⊆R is an open interval, and f:J→R is differentiable, then $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{3t}{2} f(x+th)\ dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Prove that if J⊆R is an open interval, and f:J→R is differentiable, then

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{3t}{2} f(x+th)\ dt$

How can I prove that, if I let th=s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $t\mapsto th$ reveals that $\int_{-1}^1\frac{3t}{2}f(x+th)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{3}{2h^2}\int_{-h}^htf(x+t)\mathrm{d}t$. Because $h\mapsto \int_{-h}^htf(x+t)\mathrm{d}t$ is differentiable ($\implies$ continuous) we have $\int_{-h}^htf(x+t)\mathrm{d}t\rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. Now enforce L'Hopital's rule: $$\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{-1}^1\frac{3t}{2}f(x+th)\mathrm{d}t &=& \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{3\int_{-h}^htf(x+t)\mathrm{d}t}{2h^3} \\ &=& \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{3\bigg[hf(x+h)-hf(x-h)\bigg]}{6h^2} \\ &=& \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} \\ &=& f'(x)\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I am really sorry, I couldn't get what you did here $\int_{-1}^1\frac{3t}{2}f(x+th)\mathrm{d}t=\frac{3}{2h^2}\int_{-h}^htf(x+t)\mathrm{d}t$, can you please explain it in detail for me?